# mathML is not rendering at all

Tags: html, xhtml, mathml

I have written this math equation using MathML. I have tried both using `.html` and `.xhtml`. None of them fulfilled my desire. In html format it shows `x y x y` and in .xhtml format it shows the code. So how would I make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<math display="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mode="display">
  <mfrac>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
  </mfrac>
    </math>
    <math display="block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mode="inline">
  <mfrac>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
      </mfrac>
    </math>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That [depends on what browser your're using](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml).

Comment: Which browser(s) did you test this on? It sounds like the browser just does not support MathML.

Comment: It helped me please post it as an answer! It does not support chrome so what are the other choice do I have?

Comment: Thankyou guys! I have solved my problem! please have a look at it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing a javascript from `mathjax` solved my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

complite code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax MathML Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<math display="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mode="display">
  <mfrac>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
  </mfrac>
    </math>
    <math display="block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" mode="inline">
  <mfrac>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
      </mfrac>
    </math>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).